# RPG Quests - Querying player data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, storage

Given the following table structures, where each contain a section stored about quests in an RPG. I'm trying to figure out the best way to query the current data per player.

Some information about the quest structure, It is in a 3 tier order with many Quests per Level, Within a Quest there is many Tasks per NPC to be completed but in chronological order. Also shown in the diagram:

[image]

My current layout of the design is as follows using MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE NPCs (
    ID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name varchar(50),
    RoomID int,
    X int(2),
    Y int(2),
    TypeID int,
    ImageID int,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ImageID) REFERENCES Images(ID) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (TypeID) REFERENCES NPCTypes(ID) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (RoomID) REFERENCES Rooms(ID) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Quests (
    ID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    QuestNumber int,
    Name varchar(50),
    NPCID int,
    RewardXP int(3)
    RewardMoney int(3),
    LevelID int,
    Text varchar(100),
    CompletedText varchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (LevelID) REFERENCES Levels(ID) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (NPCID) REFERENCES NPCs(ID) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE QuestStages (
    ID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    UserID int,
    QuestID int,
    Accepted bool,
    Complete bool,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES Users(ID) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (QuestID) REFERENCES Quests(ID) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE LinkedQuests (
    ID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    QuestID int,
    PreQuestID int,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (QuestID) REFERENCES Quests(ID) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (PreQuestID) REFERENCES Quests(ID) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE    
);
```

Each quest starts from a seed task and you follow through these tasks chronologically but need a easy way of querying the data.

Since the player can start, pause, and resume tasks per any NPC at a given time, I'm trying to figure out the best way to query the data in the various formats:

List of not completed Quests Quests using UserID (Quests.ID, Quests.Accepted, Quests.Name, Quests.Text, Quests.RoomID, Quests.RewardMoney , Quests.RewardXP)

Details of Select Quest using ID (Quests.ID, Quests.Name, Quest.Text/Quest.CompletedText //based if completed or not// Quests.RewardMoney , Quests.RewardXP)

Details of Quests in Room and accosted NPC using RoomID (Quests.ID, Quests.Accepted, NPCs.ID AS NPCID, NPCs.X, NPCs.Y)

EDIT Here is an example

```
Quests 
ID | QuestNumber | Name     | NPCID  | RewardXP  | RewardMoney |  LevelID | Text       | CompletedText
1  |  1          | "Quest1" |  1     |   10      |   10        |  1       |  "do this" | "Well Done"
2  |  2          | "Quest2" |  1     |   10      |   10        |  1       |  "do this" | "Well Done"
3  |  3          | "Quest3" |  2     |   10      |   10        |  1       |  "do this" | "Well Done"
4  |  4          | "Quest4" |  2     |   10      |   10        |  1       |  "do this" | "Well Done"
5  |  5          | "Quest5" |  2     |   10      |   10        |  1       |  "do this" | "Well Done"
6  |  6          | "Quest6" |  3     |   10      |   10        |  1       |  "do this" | "Well Done"

NPCs
ID   |  RoomID 
1    |  1
2    |  1
3    |  2

QuestStages 
ID| UserID | QuestID | Accepted | Complete
1 | 1      | 2       | TRUE     | FALSE
2 | 1      | 3       | TRUE     | TRUE
3 | 1      | 4       | FALSE    | FALSE
4 | 1      | 5       | TRUE     | TRUE
5 | 1      | 6       | TRUE     | FALSE

LinkedQuests
QuestID | PreQuestID
2       |  1
5       |  4
4       |  3
```

Showing list of quests for User.ID 1 1

```
Quests.ID| Quests.Accepted| Quests.Name| Quests.Text| Quests.RoomID| Quests.RewardMoney | Quests.RewardXP
3        | TRUE           | "Quest3"   |  "do this" | 1            | ... 

// will not show Quest 2 as is completed
// will not show Quest 4 as it is dependent on quest 3 being completed
```

Comment: Do you mean `RPG = Report Program Generator`? or Is `Role Playing Games`? Because if is the second case, you are using the wrong tag.

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Sorry do mean Role Playing Games

Comment: Jsut saying; http://gamedev.stackexchange.com may be a more focused place to help you.

Comment: Just updated to include example

Comment: I'm sorry but I think you need to fundamentally reorganise your data structure, unfortauntely I can't fit my head around your issue without completely rewriting your MySQL structure and I can't practically do that without knowing a lot more about your intended game dynamics. I would suggest it would help you to plan the quest *data management* system out on a drawing program or a piece of paper and then, if needed, showing us the relationships between the various data entities. Sorry

Comment: I will have a quick look over it and will post

Comment: Here is the design of the tables and how they link https://app.genmymodel.com/edit/_buDYAPexEead4oPeTNh7TQ/_buDYAvexEead4oPeTNh7TQ#

Comment: why quest 6 doesnt show? Is accepted and isnt completed.

Comment: Also quest 2 isnt complete, the complete is the 3.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/WAHV89069)** Here you can see the mid step to reach final query.

```
-- Final Output, Join to get quest details
SELECT QS.`QuestID`, QS.`Accepted`, Q.`Name`, Q.`Text`, Q.`RewardMoney`
FROM QuestStages QS
LEFT JOIN LinkedQuests LQ
  ON QS.`QuestID` = LQ.`QuestID`
LEFT JOIN QuestStages Pre
  ON QS.`UserID` = Pre.`UserID`
 AND LQ.`PreQuestID` = Pre.`QuestID`
JOIN Quests Q
  ON QS.`QuestID` = Q.`QuestNumber`
WHERE QS.`UserID` = 1
  AND QS.`Complete` = 'FALSE'
  AND (Pre.`Complete` = 'TRUE' OR Pre.`Complete` IS NULL)  
  -- Prerequirement is complete or doesnt have Prerequirement
ORDER BY QS.`QuestID`
  ;
```

**OUTPUT**, I did three steps for debug.

[image]

Comment: did you have chance to test my solution?